# Page Links in Magento 2

Tags: magento

I have created a About us page from backend and trying to link that page to the About-us at the footer. I am using:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl(''); ?>about-us"></a>
```

After clicking on About Us It's working. URL: *http://localhost/magento2/about-us* but there is a blank page, no header and footer.

Comment: We can´t access your localhost. Please provide more informations.

Comment: It is on the Local. I am using **<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl(''); ?>about-us"></a>**, is this correct?

Comment: I got it. I didn't select the layout of the page that's the reason I was getting a page without header and footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it by using Mage:

```
<a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('about-us'); ?>">About Us</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to call your page in cms content to call URL directly

```
{{store direct_url=about-us}}
```